# Dockerize MySQL together with another program

Tags: mysql, docker, go

So I have a discord but and I currently run it on a Server at home. I've now decided to set up the server from scratch. Right now I have the MySQL and the Program on the server (not in a docker container) and I now want to *Dockerize* it.

I've decided to just extend the MySQL Container for simplicity, but I keep running into errors. Right now everything works, except that the program doesn't connect to the MySQL server.

I've tried to just start the app using

```
CMD ./PokeBot
```

The result is a Connection Refused Error. First I tried to expose the port 3306 and use `127.0.0.1` as the IP for the MySQL server. Nothing worked.

I then figured that the MySQL Server wasn't running, so I created a Bash Shell Script (`.sh`) to start the MySQL server, but I then get the error `Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!`.

What can I do to run the program together with MySQL in a Docker Container?

The command I start the container with:

```sh
docker run -p 3306:3306 name
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest as builder

# That file does the DB initialization but also runs mysql daemon, by removing the last line it will only init
RUN ["sed", "-i", "s/exec \"$@\"/echo \"not running $@\"/", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# needed for intialization
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=asdfghjkl

COPY setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ADD ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

# Need to change the datadir to something else that /var/lib/mysql because the parent docker file defines it as a volume.
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume :
#       Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after
#       it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.
RUN ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "mysqld", "--datadir", "/initialized-db"]

FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=asdfghjkl

ADD ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY PokeBot /

COPY --from=builder /initialized-db /var/lib/mysql
COPY start.sh / 

EXPOSE 3306

RUN apt update
RUN apt install ca-certificates sudo -y
RUN update-ca-certificates
CMD ./start.sh
```

This is my DDL Script (after this it gets populated with data):

```sql
CREATE DATABASE pokebot;
USE pokebot;

CREATE USER 'pokebot'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'asdfghjkl';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON pokebot.* TO 'pokebot'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE TABLE image(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    srclink VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    imglink VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    command VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

My `setup.sh`:

```sh
sudo mysqld &
./PokeBot
```

Part in Go that fails:

```golang
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "pokebot:asdfghjkl@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/pokebot")

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
```

Comment: You'd almost always run these as two separate containers.  Something like the official Docker [Django and PostgreSQL](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) sample application is a different implementation language and database, but still shows how to run separate database and application containers together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I guess it is the better idea to have two containers: one for MySQL and one for your program and manage them by docker-compose.yml as two services. In that way you could change db version without touching code container. Now you need to ssh into a running container by docker exec -it   and try to connect to your db from bash to see if it works. Since your code is in the same container it should be able to do that in similar way

Comment: I basically decided to just make a docker compose. I originally wanted to just have everything in one container, so I dont have to use up the port (3306) just for this one app, but it works :D